# Execute Set of Batch Commands on Condition TRUE

Tags: batch-file, dos, batch-processing, xcopy

I have a .bat file with certain commands which it executes (XCOPY/DEL/RMDIR,etc)

Now what I want is, initially show a prompt to the user, as soon as the .bat is RUN.
Only IF the user says Y to the prompt should the complete set of commands should be executed.
ELSE it should just EXIT.
How do I do this?

Comment: `set /p input=` gets input from the user, and then you could read `if /?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set answer=N
set /P answer=Do you want to proceed? 
if /I not %answer% == Y exit /B
rem Continue here...
```

First SET command set a default value if the user just press Enter.
The /I switch in IF command ignore case in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
set /p RUN=Run [y/n]?
if %RUN% == y (
echo Run commands
) else (
exit
)
```